# Add h2-heading before (grouped) divs with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, createelement

There is a page, with divs and corresponding data-attributes (Years). The divs are sorted by post-date, so I want to visually group these together per year. I can't use PHP, because I also want to add a search-filter and still use the built-in loop-creator.

For more information: see below. Any help is much appreciated!

Question upfront: should I add a failsafe, if the data-attribute doesn't exist? To prevent errors.

This is what I would like to achieve:

**2022**

div.cm_loop_mediaposts data-year="2022"
div.cm_loop_mediaposts data-year="2022"
div.cm_loop_mediaposts data-year="2022"

**2021**

div.cm_loop_mediaposts data-year="2021"
div.cm_loop_mediaposts data-year="2021"

**2020**

div.cm_loop_mediaposts data-year="2020"
etc.

My code thus far:

```
<script>
        var div = document.querySelector('div.cm_loop_mediaposts[data-year="2022"]');
        var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.innerHTML = '2022';
        div.parentNode.insertBefore(h2, div);
</script>
<script>
        var div = document.querySelector('div.cm_loop_mediaposts[data-year="2021"]');
        var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.innerHTML = '2021';
        div.parentNode.insertBefore(h2, div);
</script>
<script>
        var div = document.querySelector('div.cm_loop_mediaposts[data-year="2020"]');
        var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.innerHTML = '2020';
        div.parentNode.insertBefore(h2, div);
</script>
<script>
        var div = document.querySelector('div.cm_loop_mediaposts[data-year="2019"]');
        var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.innerHTML = '2019';
        div.parentNode.insertBefore(h2, div);
</script>
<script>
        var div = document.querySelector('div.cm_loop_mediaposts[data-year="2018"]');
        var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.innerHTML = '2018';
        div.parentNode.insertBefore(h2, div);
</script>
```

```
<div id="brxe-ztzueq" class="brxe-container wpgb-enabled" data-instance="1">
  <!-- Gridbuilder Plugin -->
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2022"><a></a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2022"><a></a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2022"><a></a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2022"><a></a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2021"><a></a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2020"><a></a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2019"><a></a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2018"><a></a></article>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably better done within a loop. Can you post your HTML along with your Javascript?

Comment: Hello @user1280483 - thank you for your reply. I updated the post with the current html. After looking into it, I agree (and hope) that this could be possible with a loop. do { } while { }? 

My thought: it would have to scan the page for the first .cm-loop-mediaposts:nth-child(0) and save the data-year as variable (and add it before as h2). Then add +1 to :nth-child(0) and match the data-year. If not the same, add h2, etc. Until the last .cm-loop-mediaposts. Could this be a feasible approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the articles, take the property you need, group them, and then mount them under a header:

```js
const wrapperDiv = document.getElementById("brxe-ztzueq");

const result = Object.entries(
  Array.from(wrapperDiv.querySelectorAll("[data-year]"))
    .reduce(
      (p, c) => ({
        ...p,
        [c.dataset.year]: p.hasOwnProperty(c.dataset.year)
            ? [...p[c.dataset.year], c]
            : [c]
      }), {}
  )
)
  .forEach(([year, xs]) => {
    document.getElementById("mount")
      .innerHTML += `<h1>${year}</h1>`;
      
    xs.forEach(x => {
      document.getElementById("mount").appendChild(x);
    })
  })
```

```html
<div id="brxe-ztzueq" class="brxe-container wpgb-enabled" data-instance="1">
  <!-- Gridbuilder Plugin -->
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2022"><a>1</a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2022"><a>2</a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2022"><a>3</a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2022"><a>4</a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2021"><a>5</a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2020"><a>6</a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2019"><a>7</a></article>
  <article class="brxe-siebiz brxe-block cm_loop_mediaposts" data-year="2018"><a>8</a></article>
</div>
<div id="mount"></div>
```